# How to access classes with on one instance?

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, model-view-controller

I have multiple classes in the service layer of my app.
Let's say I need to access some method from AbcService.cs in my controller. Then, I need to access some method from XyzService.cs in the same controller. Then another.......For this, I would need to create an object of each Service class separately in the constructor. Also, if I needed to access these methods in another cntroller I would again have to create objects of AbcService, XyzService, etc. I want to have one instance that can give me access to methods of all service classes.
Something like:

```
generalService.AbcService.MethodName();
generalService.AbcService.MethodName();
```

How do I do this in the best possible way?

Comment: "Singleton" is the keyword you should look for. You should create a service layer with singleton pattern so that all all services can access this layer and that layer is initialized for the first time only.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me see if I can do something like that. I don't know how to do it, but I think I can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in C# you can **NOT** inherit from two classes at once so something like

```
public class CombinedService : AbcService, XyzService {

}
```

is not possible.

You can however use static methods to have only one instance per service like this:

```
public static class ServiceManager {
    // The variable holding the instance
    private static AbcService _abcService = null;
    // Access to the instance and single instance creator
    public static AbcService AbcServiceInstance {
        get {
            if (_abcService == null) {
                // Create your Instance here
                _abcService = new AbcService();
            }
            return _abcService;
        }
    }

    // The variable holding the instance
    private static XyzService _xyzService = null;
    // Access to the instance and single instance creator
    public static XyzService XyzServiceInstance {
        get {
            if (_xyzService == null) {
                // Create your Instance here
                _xyzService = new XyzService();
            }
            return _xyzService;
        }
    }
}
```

Because they are static you can access them from everywhere in the code just by calling the static class properties like this:

```
ServiceManager.AbcServiceInstance.SomeMethod();
ServiceManager.XyzServiceInstance.SomeMethod();
```

You can also shorten the instantiation and accessor like this:

```
private static AbcService _abcService = new AbcService();
public static XyzService XyzServiceInstance {
    get { return _abcService; }
}
```

If the instances can just be created like this and don't need any more parameters or configuration.

Comment: Among the similar answers, this was the first one. Hence this marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inheritance and create a class that (eventually) inherits from all of them, thus inheriting their methods. Or you can make them inherit from each other (this way you'll have to use the service class that inherits from both, as it would have all the methods that can be inherited).

To put it very simply, it can go like this using inheritance (I assume the service classes were not inheriting from anything until now):

```
public class ServiceClassA
{
  //Certain Methods
}

public class ServiceClassB : ServiceClassA
{
  //Other methods, this class also has ServiceClassA methods
}

public class ServiceClassC : ServiceClassB
{
  //Even more methods, this class also has ServiceClassA and ServiceClassB methods
}

//... and so on
```

Assuming the lowest class in the inheritance tree is ServiceClassC for example, you only need a ServiceClassC object and you'll be able to access the needed (inherited) methods.

Comment: The "class that inherits from all of them" (multiple inheritance) is not allowed in C#. I would need to use an interface then.

Comment: Yes, I know that multiple inheritance is not allowed in C#, but by "a class that inherits from all of them" I meant "A class that would end up inheriting from all of them". My bad there, I worded it wrongly.

Comment: So you mean, multi-level inheritance then??

Comment: You could put that as a way, I guess. But don't go creating empty classes that inherit from each other for the sake of getting a final class that inherits from all of them, as that would be terrible practice and inefficient. I suggest using the second method I proposed to you.

Comment: Then I am not sure how to do this. "Make them inherit from each other"...how?? What if there is no need in my code for that? Can you give me a code example or something?

Comment: I added an example to the post.

Comment: Okay I really appreciate the effort and time, but I think this is not really needed for what I am trying to achieve. I could upvote your answer because it helps, but I think I would prefer Bjorn's answer for my case. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Create service layer so that other componentns can access easily.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Global.ServiceABC.MethodA();
        Global.ServiceXYZ.MethodB();
    }
}

public class Global
{
    private static ABC serviceABC;
    public static ABC ServiceABC  { get
        {
            if (serviceABC == null)
            {
                serviceABC = new ABC();
            }
            return serviceABC;
        }
    }

    private static XYZ serviceXYZ;
    public static XYZ ServiceXYZ
    {
        get
        {
            if (serviceXYZ == null)
            {
                serviceXYZ = new XYZ();
            }
            return serviceXYZ;
        }
    }
}

public class ABC
{
    public void MethodA() { }
}

public class XYZ
{
    public void MethodB() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It somewhat depends how you choose to implement your services, but generally speaking you want some layer that encapsulate your services which is a singleton or that you inject\produce a single instance of it.

Encapsulation:

First try to look at a facade design pattern.
http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern

And btw if you don't need something complex and don't mind have an extra level of indirection then you can have some version of the facade like

```
KindOfSimpleFacade  
{
    public IServiceA ServiceA { get; }
    public IServiceB ServiceB { get; }
}
```

Regarding the singleton there are a few ways to get it:

1. inject the facade object to the (just provide the same instance to each one of the controllers as an input).
2. (Facade) Factory -http://tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm 
   The factory will produce a single instance of the facade.
3. use static members inside the facade for example:

public class KindOfSimpleFacade

```
{
    private static readonly serviceA = new ServiceA();
    private static readonly serviceB = new ServiceB();

    public IServiceA ServiceA { get { return serviceA; } }
    public IServiceB ServiceB { get { return serviceB; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a dependency injection container like [Autofac](https://autofac.org/). Register your service classes as Single Instance scope. You will get only one instance of a service class whenever you request it in every individual controller and even you do not need to create instance of it on your own.All is done by `Ioc Container`.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().SingleInstance();
```